# Break loops using while statement

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am writing a C# program that prints "true" if `number <= 20` and "false" if `number > 20` using a `while` loop but the program keeps on executing.

I want to break the program if it reaches certain number e.g. `number > 26`.

The code for the program is:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
    int numnber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (numnber <= 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
        Console.ReadLine();
        int number1 = numnber++;

        while (numnber > 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: try to decrement or increment `numnber ` by using `numnber ++;`

Comment: just add a break; when needed

Comment: =)) so fun, your inner `while` really traps your `number`, waiting for it to increase passing the value `20` and boom! it then will be trapped inside that `while` and never be able to jump out.

Comment: Is there a need of running loop at all? because you are not taking any input from user  ... alternatively you can simply use if else ...

Comment: why do you need a loop? A simple if else condition will work. If you want to keep asking the user for more tries, then in your while loop, you have to scan the number again like this: `numnber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: I don't understand your question. The problem with your code is obvious. But, what _specifically_ do you need help with? Did you try to debug the code at all? Did you try to change the code so that it would do what you want? Why did you write the code the way you did, and why can't you change it to do what you want instead?

Comment: Why "`numnber`"?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `break;` Try this:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        int numnber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (numnber <= 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
            Console.ReadLine();
            int number1 = numnber++;

            while (numnber > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            break;
        }
```

But this programming is not good at all because you are breaking loop after all for this simply you can use `if else`  like this..

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        int numnber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if(numnber <= 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
        }
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. Why start a loop if you know for sure you will break out of it in one iteration.

Comment: yes...that is why I have written in comment that no need of using loop.... and edited my answer too

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your major issue should be

> the program keeps on executing

However, it's not going to reach 26 as @King King mentioned.
It stuck inside the inner `while` which should be replaced by `if` condition.

Lastly, if you have to exec the number check at least one time you can use `do while`

```
do
{
    if (numnber <= 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
    else if (numnber > 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }

    numnber++;

    Console.WriteLine("number: {0}", numnber);

} while (numnber < 26);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all but the solution to the problem would be. The code is as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int number;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("True value. True value is supplied");
            Console.ReadLine();
            number++;

            while (number >= 21 && number < 27) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False value. False value is supplied");
                Console.ReadLine();
                number++;
            } 

        } while (number <= 20);
    } while (number > 27);
}
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block.